# FQL query of photos for Facebook users with large numbers of photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I need to get photos of an FB user sorted by likes.
I ran this FQL query via Facebook JavaScript SDK to get them:

```
SELECT object_id, src_big, src_big_width, src_big_height, link, like_info, caption, created 
FROM photo 
WHERE owner = MANY_PICS_USER_ID ORDER BY like_info DESC LIMIT 10
```

The query fails for users with more than 3000 photos. Turns out there are a lot of those users. Related Facebook bug is here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/438568326189781

As a note: removing "ORDER BY like_info" makes query work, but there is no easy way for me to get those pictures, sorted by likes

To reproduce:
Pick a FB friend with at least 3000 photos, get their user Id, and run the above query (replacing MANY_PICS_USER_ID) in API GRAPH EXPLORER.

What is the best workaround? Or, can you suggest the easiest light-weight Open Graph solution?

Comment: What happens if you use graph api calls using multi querys? This is a more basic example then all the fields you use but could be changed 
UserID?fields=photos.fields(likes).limit(10)

Comment: I would fetch the results via Graph API like TommyBs suggested then write a function that sorts the likes per photo.

Comment: Good point @AnnaVital, and probably getting 3000+ pics will require pretty big portion of traffic and memory to sort 'em.

Comment: @TommyBs how would you get around the 25 photo per query limit of FB API? There is a question about it here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6718422/1606124

Comment: Correction, currently there is 100 items limitation per Graph API call. However, 100 pics query takes so much time to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort photos by likes you need the following:

- Run the query which gives first 100 results (replace *me* with user id):

  http://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?fields=id,source,likes&limit=100

Which return the following data structure:

```
"data": [
{
  "id": "1234567890", 
  "source": "http://photo.url.in.facebook.cdn.com/", 
  "created_time": "2012-09-13T22:52:34+0000", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "1234567890", 
        "name": "Full Name"
      }, 
      .....
    "paging": {
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1234567890/likes?limit=25&offset=25"
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "312323232323", 
  "source": "PICTURE_URL", 
  "created_time": "2012-09-12T20:54:27+0000", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [..]
  }
},
....
"paging": {
  "previous": "http://PREVIOUS_URL?fields=id,source,name,height,width,link,likes&limit=100&since=123456", 
  "next": "http://NEXT_URL?fields=id,source,name,height,width,link,likes&limit=100&until=234567"
}
```

- If total number of pictures is more than 100, run all next queries,
  from the "next" link until  the num of pics will be less then 100.
- For every picture you need to count total number of likes. If the
  number of likes is more than 25, run extra query from
  likes.paging.next until number of likes will be < 25 and get the
  total quantity.
- Sort all those pics by number of likes.

So for the user with 3000 pics it will be in total 30 calls + extra calls for each picture with more than 25 likes.