# Is there a way to fetch more than 25 photos from an album with Facebook4j

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-api

I am using facebook4j to fetch photos from albums on a facebook webpage in order to make a gallery on my website.

However I cannot get more than 25 photos at once (even if there is more in the album and that the count is correct (album.getCount()).

I tried to use reading.limit() but with no success... Is it hard capped to 25 or am I doing something wrong?

```
if(null != facebookAlbum) {
            Reading reading = new Reading();
            reading.limit(100);
            ResponseList<Photo> photoResults = facebook.getAlbumPhotos(facebookAlbum.id, reading);
            Iterator<Photo> photoItr = photoResults.iterator();
            List<FacebookImage> facebookImages = new ArrayList<FacebookImage>();
            while(photoItr.hasNext()) {
                Photo photo = photoItr.next();
                FacebookImage facebookImage = new FacebookImage();
                facebookImage.imageUrl = photo.getSource().toString();
                facebookImage.album = facebookAlbum;
                facebookImages.add(facebookImage);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ResponseList<Photo> photoResults = facebook.getAlbumPhotos(facebookAlbum.id, reading.limit(0));
```

setting limit to 0 gets all the images.. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718422/getting-more-than-25-photos-from-the-facebook-graph-api) for more.